# Asyncio.Queue consumer not getting called

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an asyncio.Queue producer and consumer running as 2 infinite loops. The producer periodically adds jobs to the queue and the consumer waits until a job is available, then processes it, then waits for the next job.

However, for some reason, my consumer is not getting called. I think this is because the producer task never yields to the consumer?

Any ideas on how to fix it so that both workers run in the background as described?

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time

class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        self._duration_before_restart_ms = 3000
        self._queue = queue
        self._last_triggered_time_ms = 0

    async def consumer_loop(self):
        while True:
            print("Consumer new iteration.")
            detected_time_ms = await self._queue.get()
            print("Consumer new event: ", detected_time_ms)
            if (
                detected_time_ms - self._duration_before_restart_ms
                < self._last_triggered_time_ms
            ):
                print("Consumer skipping event: ", detected_time_ms)
                # Invalidate all items in queue that happened before
                # _last_triggered_time_ms.
                continue
            print("Consumer processing event: ", detected_time_ms)
            # Simulate authentication (an io bound operation) with sleep.
            time.sleep(5)
            self._last_triggered_time_ms = int(time.time() * 1000)
            print(
                "Consumer processed event: ",
                detected_time_ms,
                " at: ",
                self._last_triggered_time_ms,
            )


class Producer:
    def __init__(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        self._detection_time_period_ms = 3000
        self._last_detection_time_ms = 0
        self._queue = queue

    async def producer_loop(self):
        counter = 0
        while True:
            # Iterates at 2fps
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Producer counter: ", counter)
            current_time_ms = int(time.time() * 1000)

            if (counter % 10 > 5) and (
                self._last_detection_time_ms + self._detection_time_period_ms
                < current_time_ms
            ):
                print("Producer adding to queue: ", current_time_ms)
                await self._queue.put(current_time_ms)
                print("Producer added to queue: ", current_time_ms)
                self._last_detection_time_ms = current_time_ms
            counter += 1


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    producer = Producer(q)
    consumer = Consumer(q)
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer.producer_loop())
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer.consumer_loop())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is executed. This way you may see if consumer is running. Maybe code wait for end of producer loop.

Comment: BTW: if you use `asyncio` then you could use also `asyncio.wait()` instead of `time.wait()`

Comment: The consumer doesn't run at all.

Comment: if I use `await asyncio.sleep(...)` (in both functions) (instead of time.sleep()) then it has time to switch tasks and consumer has time to get data from queue. It need also `await asyncio.gather(producer_task)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works for me if I use `await asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()`

In `async` taks don't run at the same time but it should switch task when it see `await` - and it seems it needs `await asyncio.sleep()` to have time to switch from producer to customer, and later to switch back from customer to producer.

You have `await` in `put()` and `get()` but I can't explain why it doesn't switch tasks. Maybe it swithc but it switch too fast and it had not enough time to send data in queue.

---

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

class Consumer:

    def __init__(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        self._duration_before_restart_ms = 3000
        self._queue = queue
        self._last_triggered_time_ms = 0

    async def consumer_loop(self):
        print('start consumer')

        while True:
            print("Consumer new iteration.")
            detected_time_ms = await self._queue.get()
            print("Consumer new event: ", detected_time_ms)
            if (
                detected_time_ms - self._duration_before_restart_ms
                < self._last_triggered_time_ms
            ):
                print("Consumer skipping event: ", detected_time_ms)
                # Invalidate all items in queue that happened before
                # _last_triggered_time_ms.
                continue
            print("Consumer processing event: ", detected_time_ms)
            # Simulate authentication (an io bound operation) with sleep.
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            self._last_triggered_time_ms = int(time.time() * 1000)
            print(
                "Consumer processed event: ",
                detected_time_ms,
                " at: ",
                self._last_triggered_time_ms,
            )


class Producer:

    def __init__(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        self._detection_time_period_ms = 3000
        self._last_detection_time_ms = 0
        self._queue = queue

    async def producer_loop(self):
        print('start producer')

        counter = 0
        while True:
            # Iterates at 2fps
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
            print("Producer counter: ", counter)
            current_time_ms = int(time.time() * 1000)

            if (counter % 10 > 5) and (
                self._last_detection_time_ms + self._detection_time_period_ms
                < current_time_ms
            ):
                print("Producer adding to queue: ", current_time_ms)
                await self._queue.put(current_time_ms)
                print("Producer added to queue: ", current_time_ms)
                self._last_detection_time_ms = current_time_ms
            counter += 1


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    producer = Producer(q)
    consumer = Consumer(q)
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer.producer_loop())
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer.consumer_loop())

    # wait for end of task
    await asyncio.gather(producer_task)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```